# CGContextFillRect with Pattern image and bind image to top left corner of rect

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-graphics

Is it possible to use CGContextFillRect with Pattern image (`[UIColor colorWithImage:@"Image.png"]`) but "bind" initial image to top left corner of rect being drawn?

Comment: are you trying to fix its position to top left corner?

Comment: @dig, please find the updated ans below and make it correct. If it really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desired result can be achieved by means of

```
CGContextSetPatternPhase(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0));
```

See documentation [CGContextSetPatternPhase](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetPatternPhase)